# MSVC generates slow code for array destruction with user-provided destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why adding an empty destructor in `struct Simple` in the following code makes MSVC generate a lot of code that in this case is essentially a no-op (in my opinion)?

```
struct Simple
{
    int m_member;
#if 0
    inline ~Simple() noexcept {
    }
#endif
};

struct Node
{
    Simple m_data[2];
};

void Test2(Node* p){
    delete p;
}
```

The problem is clearly visible with compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/fFOvI5 . There's a lot going on during the destruction for MSVC compiler, while GCC and Clang both produce just a call to delete(void*, size_t) or delete(void*).

The actual use case is that I had a pointer in a simple struct that is private to .cpp and wanted to add asserts to make sure that the implementation logic correctly null-ifies pointers (moves pointer values out of pointers) before deleting these structs. The structs are allocated on heap, so optimizations don't help much. The code is deemed to be performance-critical, so no std::unique_ptr.

edit: the versions in question: MSVC 2019; GCC 9.2 and Clang 9.0.0 but I think any will suffice.

edit2: adding destructor does produce noticeable performance degradation.

Comment: `= default` for the dtor seems to make a difference

Comment: A user defined destructor is *never* trivial, not even if it is empty. Use `~Simple() = default;` instead. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial

Comment: *"The code is deemed to be performance-critical, so no `std::unique_ptr`."* How `std::unique_ptr` impacts performance?

Comment: A `std::unique_ptr` is a very thin abstraction that is designed to be optimized away completely by the compilers optimizer (or at the very least reduce down to something you cannot implement more efficiently yourself). Avoiding `std::unique_ptr` for performance reasons is a mistake.

Comment: Actually, in this case we measured performance difference with unique_ptr vs naked pointers and manually calling delete. In this specific case it was worth it. On the other hand, I do agree that not using unique_ptr vs naked pointers is almost always a mistake. See also recent talk at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHIkrotSwcc . Anyway, it's a bit offtopic.

Comment: The Standard does not require non-trivial destructor to cause performance degradation against trivial destructor, as clearly demonstrated by GCC and Clang implementations.  Anyway I think it's more related to ABI rather than optimization failure or anything like that.

Comment: @smitsyn Nice talk, thank you for the link.